# Not showing recently entered data in Grid after using Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I had a perfectly working system showing recently entered data on a grid as soon as i saved the data. after using ajax the data is entered but the newly entered data is shown if i reload the page.
On Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        RoleBusinessLayer roleBusinessLayer = new RoleBusinessLayer();
        List<Role> roles = roleBusinessLayer.Roles.ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = roles;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Role role)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            RoleBusinessLayer roleBusinessLayer = new RoleBusinessLayer();
            roleBusinessLayer.SaveRole(role);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }            
    }
```

On View:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SaveRole').click(function () {
            var data = $('#RoleForm').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url: '/Role/Index',
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("Role Information Saved!");
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

what should i do to show the newly entered data on the grid as soon as i click the save button?

Comment: you'd have to write some JavaScript code to add the necessary HTML to your grid (probably best to do it in the "success" method of your ajax call, so you know it was definitely saved to the database. Or you could make your ajax call return some data - either JSON, or HTML (from a partial view) with which you can re-populate your grid. What have you researched or tried so far?

Comment: yeah, already got that by simply adding window.location. thank you.

Comment: That's not the same thing as an Ajax request at all. It's just the equivalent of reloading the page. It sounded like you wanted to avoid doing that.

Comment: Yeah, that's right! i ended up reloading that page. but i don't see other ways without adding a list to my post method too, which breaks the dry principle. any idea what else i can do?

Comment: if you want to avoid that you could just write some JavaScript to manually add a row of HTML to your grid, as I suggested. P.S. I don't see it as particularly problematic from a design point of view to return the same list from two action methods - you can still have shared logic in a separate method / class which both methods use to actually build the list.

Comment: P.S. Your "Index" GET method doesn't return a model...I don't understand why you're putting your list of Roles into the ViewBag, if they're the main subject of the view then they should be defined as the Model for the page i.e. `@model List<Role>`, otherwise you're missing the entire point of MVC. ViewBag is just for little random extras like message text or items to populate a dropdownlist, not for the main page data.

Comment: P.P.S. In your POST method, since you're using AJAX to call it, neither 
 returning a whole View or returning a Redirect (both of which are possible outcomes) makes any sense - you wouldn't want to return the whole view because that's an entire copy of your page. Instead return either a Partial View containing HTML for the updated grid, or return some JSON which contains maybe the _data_ for the the grid, or just something brief to indicate status. And redirecting makes no sense because the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page and avoid redirects/reloads etc.